# Prove that the limit $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3 - n^2}}\right)^n$ doesn't exist or find it

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

Given $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3 - n^2}}\right)^n$.

My attempt: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3 - n^2}}\right)^n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)^n$. So as the  $n \to \infty \Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n} \to 1$.

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)^n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$.

However, I'm not sure that my proof is strict enough, especially the moment, where I go from $\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}$ to $1$.

Comment: This looks fine.

Comment: @Jed No, it is not. The OP cannot do the step where the limit $1$ goes "in the parenthesis" like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)^n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$.
>
> However, I'm not sure that my proof is strict enough, especially the moment, where I go from $\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}$ to $1$.

Indeed, this step is not correct, and you need to justify why this is fine (under other circumstances, very similar-looking, it may not give the right result).

As almost always there is a doubt or some non-trivial step to be made, in this situation I would suggest to rewrite the quantity in the exponential form *(below, very detailed derivation)*:
$$
\left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)^n
= \exp\left(n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right) \right)
$$
Now,
$$\begin{align}
n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\cdot  n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n} \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\cdot  \frac{\ln \left(1 + a_n\right)}{a_n}
\end{align}$$
setting $a_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{1}{n\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$. Recalling that $\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}\xrightarrow[u\to0]{}1$, we get that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\cdot  \frac{\ln \left(1 + a_n\right)}{a_n}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot 1=1
$$
and therefore
$$
\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1 - 1/n}}\cdot  \frac{\ln \left(1 + a_n\right)}{a_n}\right)
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^1 = e
$$
by continuity of the exponential.

Comment: +1 I believe that it is very nice, and a good reference.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear: the specific "problematic step" made by the OP gives the right result, and can be justified (as it *needs* to) with a long theorem/statement very *ad hoc*. But trying to do these manipulations can only bring errors in the long term (I was going to write "doom"), as memorizing when it works, when it doesn't, etc. is much less simple and much more error-prone than just deriving it every time.

Answer (score 2):

The end result is correct, but your last step lacks rigour. Since our limit is of the form "$1^\infty$", the usual trick will do:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}} \right) ^n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left[ \left( 1 + \frac 1 {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}} \right) ^{\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}} \right] ^{\frac n {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}}} = \\
\left[ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1 {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}} \right) ^{\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}} \right] ^{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac n {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}}} = \Bbb e ^{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac n {\sqrt[3] {n^3 - n^2}}} = \Bbb e ^1 = \Bbb e.$$

"The usual trick" that I have mentioned is the following: whenever you have to study a limit of the type $\left( 1 + \frac 1 {x_n} \right) ^{y_n}$ with $x_n, y_n \to \infty$, rewrite it as

$$\left[ \left( 1 + \frac 1 {x_n} \right) ^{x_n} \right] ^{\frac {y_n} {x_n}}$$

and use the fact that $\left( 1 + \frac 1 {x_n} \right) ^{x_n} \to \Bbb e$. The whole difficulty of the exrcise becomes, then, the computation of $\lim \frac {y_n} {x_n}$ which in many cases is considerably simpler than any other approach that you might consider.

Comment: Can you please clarify, when I can go from $\lim \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\right]^{\frac{y_n}{x_n}}$ to $\lim \left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\right]^{\lim \frac{y_n}{x_n}}$? When both limits exist?

Comment: @FalsePromise: Yes, the equality is true when both limits exist. Furthermore, if $x_n \to \infty$ then the quantity $\left(1 + \frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}$ is *guaranteed* to tend to $\Bbb e$, so you need not worry about it anymore. This means that in this case the equality that you are asking about is true whenever $\frac {y_n} {x_n}$ exists.

Comment: So, assume that I want to find $\lim f(g(x))$, then if $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exist, then $\lim f(g(x)) =  \lim f( \lim g(x))$? Does this work because of the composition law for limits?
What is the generic case when I can "split" one limit into two or more?

Answer (score 0):

The last equality should be explained. At any case we can use that if $a_n\to 1$ and $b_n\to \infty$ then, 
$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^{b_n}=e^{\lambda} \text{ where } \lambda=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n-1){b_n}.$$ In our case, $\lambda=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2}}=\ldots=1, \text{ so } L=e^1=e.$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the step you're doubtful upon is a quite a dangerous jump.

You can use functions rather than sequences, if possible. And, with exponentials with variable basis, pass to logarithms. If you find the limit of the logarithm to be $l$, then your limit is $e^l$ (or $0$ if $l=-\infty$, or $\infty$ if $l=\infty$). If the function has limit at $\infty$, the sequence shares it.

Thus you need
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3 - x^2}}\right)
$$
Now, this limit (provided it exists) is the same as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{t}\log\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt[3]{1-t}}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{t}{\sqrt[3]{1-t}}+o(t)}{t}=1
$$
Without Taylor, set $\sqrt[3]{1-t}=u$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to1^-}\frac{\log(1+u-u^3)-\log u}{1-u^3}=
\lim_{u\to1^-}\frac{\log u-\log(1+u-u^3)}{u-1}\frac{1}{u^2+u+1}
$$
The second factor has limit $1/3$; the first factor provides the derivative at $1$ of the function $f(u)=\log u-\log(1+u-u^3)$; since
$$
f'(u)=\frac{1}{u}-\frac{1-3u^2}{1+u-u^3}
$$
we get
$$
f'(1)=1-\frac{1-3}{1+1-1}=3
$$
and so the limit is $1$.

Finally, the sought limit is $e^1=e$.